# Blazor retrieve relative url

Tags: url-routing, blazor, relative-url

I am looking to retrieve the relative part of the current Blazor page URL.

For example if I am currently on  *https://www.mywebsite.com/someoverview*, I wish to retrieve */someoverview*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not Blazor specific, we have the Uri class:

```
var uri = new Uri(@"https://www.mywebsite.com/someoverview");
var relativePath = uri.LocalPath;  // or .PathAndQuery
```

or for the current Blazor page:

```
@inject NavigationManager Navigator

<a href="@Navigator.ToBaseRelativePath(Navigator.Uri)">here</a>
```

but do note that ToBaseRelativePath() does not include a leading `/`, it is different from LocalPath.  You can mix & match.